# Gaming center set up?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

I have a video game store that has 9 pay n play stations. I have 1 wired d-link ebr-2310 router comes right off my dsl modem that my cash registers are hooked up to. There are 4 ports on the back, 2 are used by the cash registers and I have 2 trendnet tew-692gr wireless routers for the pay n play center.

Can you recommend the best setup, so my gamers have the best connection possible. I have 4 PS3 stations and 4 xbox 360 stations and the last station has a 73 inch internet ready TV, a PS3, an xbox360 and a Wii.

Answer (score 4):

> dsl modem

Switch to Fiber Optic.  You want your PAYING customers to have the best connection possible, then you need to PAY for the best connection possible.  That means getting an ISP that can provide you with a fantastic bandwidth package.

Think about it this way.  All the packages offered for Home users... all that bandwidth offered in those packages is generally for one or two gamers at a time.  Sure.  Some people can pull off a few more consoles being connected AND playing online at the same time, but not really.  So, multiply that 10mbps package by a factor of 5 and you start to see what you would need to have about 10 people with good connections on one plan.  50mbps.  100mbps would be even better.

**THAT'S** where you start.  Now, I have no idea what speed you have for your current plan.  You didn't say.  But the fact that you are running it all off a DSL modem implies you need to upgrade your connection speed.

**EDIT** and make sure none of the consoles are using a wireless connection to get online.  The last thing you need are a couple of people using bluetooth headsets in the place to disrupt the wireless connections between the consoles and the routers.

Comment: And even worse if it's ADSL (which most DSL connections are), which typically has horrible upstream speeds for home connections... which could be a problem for some games.

Comment: @Bob absolutely.  Home gamers can put up with a bit of lag here and there... but people walking into a business and paying good money by the minute/hour/game shouldn't have to stand for ANY connection issues whatsoever.  Any gaming salon that doesn't pay top dollar for a top connection should just send their customers home with a subscription to GameFly.